# Ajax beginform don't work with not empty values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

So, I have a problem. When I send a request to the controller with all the empty data, the query is working, and I can debug it on my controller, but when I add at least one value to the query, the form stops working at all. No result, errors, etc. I use partial views to skip the addition forms.

layout scripts:

- jquery.3.3.1.min.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
- jquery.validate.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
- bootstrap.js
- respond.js

all scripts at the bottom of the page.

my ajax begin form

```
@model AttanctionTest.Models.TestParam


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestParamApply", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "PartialViewId" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    if (ViewBag.Action == "Set")
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionStr" value="Set" />
        <p>Добавить запись</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionStr" value="Update" />
        <p>Изменить запись</p>
    }

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Количество вопросов", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountQuestion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Время теста", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Время появления фигуры", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FigureTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FigureTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="Применить" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult TestParamApply(string ActionStr, TestParam testParam, int? Id)
        {
            switch (ActionStr)
            {
                case "Set":
                    SQLite.Set(testParam);
                    break;
                case "Update":
                    SQLite.Update(testParam);
                    break;
                case "Delete":
                    var list = SQLite.Get<TestParam>().Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    SQLite.Delete(list);
                    break;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ListView", new { Table = "TestParam" });
        }
```

Comment: Maybe because of the cyrillic chars or other non-ASCII characters in the url parameters? Have you tried `encodeURIComponent()` before submitting your form?

Comment: no, I deleted all russian words and query didn't work... again...

Comment: Maybe you can add your request and the payload to the question.

Comment: How? I don't know what's happened after clicked the button. It's asp, I written code at Visual Studio, what I need to do that I get the post query and look what's data from it?

Comment: Your using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which makes an ajax request, so your `return RedirectToAction()` makes no sense (ajax calls cannot redirect)

Comment: This would be a problem if I had a request to go into the controller, it does not even reach the controller

Comment: Take a look in your browser Networkpanel. In chrome you can open the Dev Tools by pressing F12 (Windows)

Comment: Status query 200 OK, but nothig happened

Comment: `http://localhost:2905/Admin/TestParamApply/3?ActionStr=Delete` it's delete query, status 200, but record didn't delete